# Image resize onhover with css

Tags: css, image-resizing

I have a small issue with some code. I am trying to achieve the effect of image resizing done with css, in a small slider. The thing is that the image is only shown inside the frame it's into.
How can i make it work to display the image in it's full size?
The page i am trying to implement this is [here](http://www.ambalajepersonalizate.ro/sacose-personalizate/sacose-banana-personalizate.php), on the first slider.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 30vh;
  height: 30vh;
  margin: 5vh;
}

img:hover {
  width: 70vh;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: 15vh;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AXkkbmFRErs/TjCZIWGawfI/AAAAAAAAAlk/lT8yTGBYh38/s1600/Rick-Roll3.png">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
Hover over me, please!
```

Is this essentially what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi! That is the effect, but it still doesn't leave the initial border and i can't see why.

Comment: @Daniel I am sorry, but what do you mean by "the initial border"? You can make it move wherever you want.

Comment: Hi!Thanks for the reply. A friend of mine helped me with it and now is ok. He had to apply some changes on the slider that was there also.

Comment: @Daniel If this answer solved your problem, then please "Accept" it to close the question.